# How to pass "NULL" value into nullable field during call from JavaScript to ASP.NET WebService

Tags: c#, javascript, json, web-services

How to pass "NULL" value into nullable field during call from JavaScript to ASP.NET WebService?

I call method in the following way from JavaScript:

```
ws_data.SaveTasks(eval({"MyValue":"null"}), OnSaveComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
```

When I do, I receive an error (framework calls OnError):

> null is not a valid value for Int32

If instead of "null" I pass valid integer - everything works fine.

**Please advise: What I do wrong? How to pass 'null' value which will be 'translated' into a NULL .NET object?**

Any ideas are welcome!

P.S. Here are some details.

Declaration of essential part of MyData:

```
public class MyData
{
    ...
    public int? MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Declaration of ASP.NET web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "...")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ws_data : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(true)]
    public object SaveData(MyData data)
    {...}
}
```

And ws_data is declared via ScriptManager:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="/ws_data.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Did you tried to not passing anything?

Comment: Pass `null`, not string `"null"`.

Comment: if its Nullable why do you even want to pass anything?

Comment: I didn't try to not pass anything... looks like that is an idea. But i prefer explicit declaration. Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're passing the string null instead of the non-value null.  Remove the quotes to make it an actual null.

```
{"MyValue": null}
```

I'm not sure about your `eval` either, I think it can be omitted as `eval` is supposed to take a string an interpret it as JavaScript.

```
ws_data.SaveTasks({"MyValue": null}, OnSaveComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
```